# What is this error in my MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Why this error occurs when pressing foreign key in the chat table?

```
create table user ( id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
    userId int, username varchar(250),
    useremail varchar(250),
primary key(id,userId));

CREATE table chat ( Id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
   userId int, chatmsg varchar(250),  time timestamp,
   primary key(id),  
   foreign key (userId) references user (userId) 
       on update cascade on delete cascade);
```

Comment: What error are you getting? (Side note: it is not considered good practice to mark questions as urgent here. They are answered by volunteers, who will respond at their leisure).

Comment: @halfer: Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

There is no index on table `user` with leading column of `userid`. (That's why InnoDB is throwing an error on the FOREIGN KEY definition. InnoDB requires that there be a suitable index.)

If the tuple `(id, userid)` is defined as the PRIMARY KEY of the `user` table, the normative pattern would be for a foreign key reference to reference both of those columns.

But do you really need to have combination of the two columns as the PRIMARY KEY?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE user 
( 
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'pk',
     username VARCHAR(250),
     useremail VARCHAR(250), 
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE chat
( 
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'pk',
     user_id INT COMMENT 'fk ref user(id)', 
     chatmsg VARCHAR(250),
     time TIMESTAMP,
     PRIMARY KEY (id),
     CONSTRAINT FK_chat_user
         FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id)
             ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

If you always want a row in `chat` associated with a `user`, then you can have the database enforce that by adding `NOT NULL` to the `user_id` column of `chat`.

Comment: Thank You for your kind cooperation and prompt attention to my request.

Answer (score 0):

declare user table in this way

```
create table user ( 
     id        int NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     userId    int, 
     username  varchar(250), 
     useremail varchar(250), 
     primary key(id), key(userId)
);
```

Comment: Thank You for your kind cooperation and prompt attention to my request.

Answer (score 0):

Try out following queries to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `useremail` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `userId_UNIQUE` (`userId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `chat` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chatmsg` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `fk_userid_idx` (`userId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_userid` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Thank You for your kind cooperation and prompt attention to my request.